# Perl pattern matching "nothing"/empty

Tags: regex, perl

This is driving me nuts!

1. I read a txt file into a string called $filestring.

   ```
   sysopen(handle, $filepath, O_RDONLY) or die "WHAT?";
   local $/ = undef;
   my $filestring = <handle>;
   ```
2. I made a pattern variable called $regex which is generated dynamically, but takes on the format:

   ```
   (a)|(b)|(c)
   ```
3. I search the text for patterns separated by a space

   ```
   while($filestring =~ m/($regex)\s($regex)/g){
      print "Match: $1 $2\n";
      #...more stuff
   }
   ```

Most of the matches are valid, but for some reason I get a match like the following every once and a while:

```
Match: and
```

whereas a normal match should have two outputs like the following:

```
Match: , and
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

EDIT: it appears that the NULL character is being matched in the pattern.

Comment: One of the subpatterns matches the empty string? Could it contain metacharacters which ought to be escaped?

Comment: What's in `$regex` in these cases?

Comment: Words numbers and punctuation such as ? . ,
I've made sure to escape these character as needed.

Comment: A non-printable character in the input file?

Comment: Hmm maybe but I couldn't say for certain; is there a way to catch such a thing?

Comment: Print `ord($1)` as a diagnostic.

Comment: For my problem case I have $1 outputting 116, and $2 outputting 0.
The Display is 
Match: the

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of the alternatives in your regexp is a separate capture group. The whole regexp looks like:

```
((a)|(b)|(c))\s((a)|(b)|(c))
12   3   4     56   7   8
```

I've notated it with the capture group number for each piece of the regexp.

So if `$filestring` is `b a`, `$1` will be `b`, `$2` will be the empty strying because nothing matched `(a)`.

To avoid this, you should use non-capturing groups for the alternatives:

```
((?:a)|(?:b)|(?:c))\s((?:a)|(?:b)|(?:c))
```